# Treat Maven warnings as errors

Tags: maven

How can I treat Maven warnings as errors? Not just compiler warnings, but all warnings. For example, I want these warnings to be treated as errors that will fail the build:

```
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for <>
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for <> should not point at files within the project directory, <> will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line <>, column <>
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.(groupId:artifactId)' must be unique but found duplicate declaration of plugin org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin @ line <>, column <>
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
```

Comment: And as is said on the linked JIRA ticket, the warnings you're having can be treated as errors with the Maven Enforcer Plugin, I think it already has rules for some the warnings you have.